# Statsmodels sarimax : turn process output off

Tags: statsmodels

I'm using the Statsmodels statespace sarimax like so:

```
model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(param1, param2, etc)
fit_model = model.fit()
```

When this process is running, there's an output of the process printed on the terminal, see below:

[image]

Is there a way to turn this output off?

Comment: This is the output of the optimizer scipy fmin_lbfgsb. `fit` keyword disp=0 might work.

Comment: This works, thanks you!

Answer (score 10):

Set `disp` to `False` explicitly:

```
fit_model = model.fit(disp=False)
```